# Java - Add an object without reference to the original object

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to build a "HashMap< String,ArrayList< String>>" with the same ArrayList cleaning it and putting it again with different values.

The problem comes when the HashMap automatically updates all it's content when I update the ArrayList.

I update the HashMap with "put" and the same variable with different value as a key.

Is there any way to load the data?

The code is the next:

`
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

```
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("testFile"))) {

            // read line by line
            String line;
            Map<String,ArrayList<String>> trigg = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
            Map<String,Map<String,ArrayList<String>>> charac = new HashMap<String,Map<String,ArrayList<String>>>();
            ArrayList<String> cond = new ArrayList<String>();
            String triggName = "";
            String condName = "";

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
                if (line.length() > 3) {

                if (line.charAt(0) == (char) 9 && line.charAt(1) == (char) 9 && line.charAt(2) == (char) 9 && line.charAt(3) == (char) 9) {
                        cond.add(line);


                }else if (line.charAt(0) == (char) 9 && line.charAt(1) == (char) 9 && line.charAt(2) == (char) 9) {
                        if (condName != "" && cond.get(0) != null) {
                            trigg.put(condName+"", new ArrayList<String>() {{
                                for (String st : cond) {
                                    add(st);
                                }
                            }});

                        }
                        cond.clear();
                        condName = line.split("\\[")[1].split("]")[0];


                } else if (line.charAt(0) == (char) 9 && line.charAt(1) == (char) 9) {
                    System.out.println(cond + condName);
                    if (condName.equals("C2")) {
                        System.out.println(trigg);
                    }
                    if (condName != "" && cond.get(0) != null) {
                        trigg.put(condName, new ArrayList<String>() {{
                            for (String st : cond) {
                                add(st);
                            }
                        }});

                        for(Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<String>> entry : trigg.entrySet()) {
                            String key = entry.getKey();
                            ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();

                            charac.put(triggName, Map.of(key,value));

                        }

                    }

                    cond.clear();
                    condName = "";

                    triggName = line.split("\\[")[1].split("]")[0];

                } else if (line.charAt(0) == (char) 9) {
                    //System.out.println("Un solo tab " + line);

                } else {
                    //System.out.println("No hay tabs " + line);
                }
            }
            }

            trigg.put(condName, new ArrayList<String>() {{
                for (String st : cond) {
                    add(st);
                }
            }});;
            charac.put(triggName,trigg);;
            for(Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<String>> entry : trigg.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();

                charac.put(triggName, Map.of(key,value));

            }
            System.out.println(charac);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }`
```

The file I'm reading is:

```
[SPEECH]
[character]
    [loc1]
        [C1]
            =test1
    [loc2]
        [C1]
            test2
            =test3
        [C2]
            test4
    [loc3]
        [C1]
            test5
            =test6
        [C2]
            test7
            =test8
            =test9
```

This should build a character HashMap with all this content sorted with the same hierarchy, but when I load more than one C* ArrayList for the same loc, the last C* that existed in the same loc is removed.

The output I'm getting is:

```
{loc2={C2=[             test4]}, loc3={C2=[             test7,              =test8,                 =test9]}, loc1={C1=[                =test1]}}
```

I don't know where I'm pissing it.

Comment: Fixed!!! I have replaced the code for putting things into charac for `charac.put(triggName, new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>());
       charac.get(triggName).putAll(trigg);`. Now everything works fine. Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to build a `HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>` with the same ArrayList cleaning it and putting it again with different values.

That's the wrong way, since all the keys of your `HashMap` are mapped to the same `ArrayList` object.

Instead of trying to re-use the same `ArrayList` object, you should create a new `ArrayList` each time you put a new entry in the `HashMap`.

Comment: I fixed that problem, but now, my problem is the key. Now I'm generating a new ArrayList object, but don't know how could I get the value of my String variable instead of using the same variable as a key.

Comment: @Roberto what's your problem with the key? Please edit your question with relevant code. Otherwise it's hard to answer.

Comment: I build the array, and I do HashMap.put(miStringVariable, new ArrayList(String){ add("whatever") }).  Let me try to add an example of what happens.

Comment: Thanks @RealSkeptic, will try to fix all things you said and try it again. Really appreciate the help!!

Comment: Still unable to make it, cause with compute will edit current entries. My problem is now that when I put a C2 array into a loc map, the C1 that existed before is replaced by the new one.